# How to get __declspec(thread) working on Windows CE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, visual-c++-2008

I have a class containing:

```
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass *previous;
    static __declspec(thread) SomeClass *stackTop;

public:
    SomeClass() : previous(stackTop) { stackTop = this; }
    ~SomeClass() { stackTop = previous; }
};

__declspec(thread) SomeClass *SomeClass::stackTop = NULL;
```

This compiles fine for `Win32` target, but when compiling for `Pocket PC 2003 (ARMV4)` fails with error C2485:

```
error C2485: '$I' : unrecognized extended attribute
```

in the two places where I set the member in `SomeClass` constructor and destructor and in all places where I instantiate `SomeClass` (it is instantiated as automatic variable and needs to know where the next instance higher up the stack is).

Unfortunately the error has no meaningful documentation in MSDN and the documentation for `__declspec(thread)` does not indicate any conditions under which it will not work. I did check that `thread` is not defined in preprocessor.

Comment: Looks like a code generate limitation.  Post to connect.microsoft.com to get the official "we don't support this" story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that version of Pocket PC (Windows CE) supports the `__declspec(thread)` attribute (TLS). It would explain why this only comes up when you're compiling for Pocket PC but not for Win32. See the following links:

- [Windows CE does not
  support the __declspec(thread)
  attribute](http://www.pocketpcjunkies.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/wince-prog/530/TLS-issue-unresolved-extenal-tls-array)
- [__declspec (thread) returns
  error](http://www.pocketpcjunkies.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/wince-vc/4525/declspec-thread-returns-error)

Comment: Seems so. I am going to wrap `TlsAlloc`/`TlsGetValue`/`TlsSetValue` in a C++0x-compliant (almost; I won't bother with cleanup function I don't need) wrapper.